# Mapping integer does not work in ElasticSearch

Tags: python, elasticsearch, mapping

I created an index "activities" and bulked all the data from a csv. However, everything is of type "text" and some values should be of type "integer", "long", "double". I tried the following with no success. What am I doing wrong?

```
es.indices.create(index='activities')

#mapping datatype
es.indices.put_mapping(
    index="activities",
    include_type_name=True,
    doc_type="activity_body",
    body={
        "activity_body":{
        "properties": {"ActivitatID": {"type": "long"},
                       "Assignaturas": {"type": "text"},
                       "Competencias": {"type": "text"},
                       "Descripcion": {"type": "text"}, 
                       "EdadMaxima": {"type": "integer"},
                       "EdadMinima": {"type": "integer"},
                       "Guardados": {"type": "integer"},
                       "Idioma": {"type": "text"}, 
                       "Link": {"type": "text"},
                       "Nombre": {"type": "text"}, 
                       "Puntuacion": {"type": "double"},
                       "Tags": { "type": "text"},
                       "Votos": {"type": "integer"},
                       "Tipo": {"type": "text"}
                      }
        }
    }
)

#open file and load all data to elasticsearch
with open(file_path) as f:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f)
    helpers.bulk(es, reader, index="activities")
```

Thanks

Comment: To help you we will need to have an example of data you use. It is probably an issue when you read the CSV file and python doesn't infer properly types.

Comment: I don't think is due to that. Actually, I noticed after doing some range queries that it works, I mean, they are integer not text after trying this. The strange thing is that when I do some GET() in insomnia, they show like "12" instead of 12.

Comment: It seems like the issue looks like the same as in [ES forum](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/strings-in-integer-fields/58301).
Basically you have to be sure that it is correct integer. ES can infer the type if it looks like an integer but it'll keep the original format. Could you to force integer when you read the csv and check if it is ok?

Comment: Do you mean iterate every row of the csv to indicate what is an integer?